# Member function of my class not recognizing that one of my classes variables exists

Tags: c++, class

I have a header file which contains the following:

```
class myImage
{
private:
    unsigned char **img;
    int xpixels;
    int ypixels;
public:
    myImage(int x, int y);
    ~myImage();
    int getX();
    int getY();
    unsigned char **getImage();
    void setImage(unsigned char ** uc_img);
};
```

And a cpp file that references the header file:

```
#include "img.h"

myImage::myImage(int x, int y)
{
    xpixels=x; ypixels=y;
    img= new unsigned char*[y];
    for(int i=0; i<y;++i)
    {
        img[i]=new unsigned char[x];
    }
    for (int i=0;i<y;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<x;j++)
        {
            img[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
} 

myImage::~myImage()
{
    for(int i=0; i<ypixels;++i)
    delete[] img[i];
    delete[] img;
} 

int myImage::getX()
{
    return xpixels;
}

int myImage::getY()
{
    return ypixels;
}

unsigned char **getImage()
{
    return img;
}
```

However, my getImage function is not recognising that img exists, and I'm not sure why. Could anyone explain to me why not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the class name prepended to the function name.

Make it `myImage::getImage()`